# Futures timed out after [10000] milliseconds

Tags: java, unit-testing, debugging, timeout, playframework-2.2

I am trying to debug unit tests in play and I am running into timeouts every time.

> Error: Futures timed out after [10000] milliseconds

I was wondering how I can manually increase the timeout in Play 2.2.6 with Java?

Also, I cannot update to 2.3 at the moment.

Comment: I'd probably look into why it's taking more than 10 seconds.

Comment: @Lachian I guess it's because he is debugging..

Answer (score 0):

In your test class, put this initialization block, which sets the time out to 5 minutes:

```
public Test {

    public static final long DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = 5 * 60000L;

    static {
        System.setProperty("test.timeout", Long.toString(DEFAULT_TIMEOUT));
    }
}
```